# Python RLock IO-Bound?

Tags: python, synchronization, multiprocessing, cpu-usage

I have a set of CPU-bound processes that take any number of cores to 100% utilization as long as their only synchronization is getting jobs out of a Queue.

As soon as I add an RLock to avoid worst case scenarios when updating a directory in the file system, CPU/core utilization drops to 60%, as if the processes had become IO-bound.

What's the explanation?

This is not about overall speed. It is about CPU/core utilization, so Python 2/3, Cython, or PyPy should not matter.

**Update:** I gave a partial answer to my own question. The final solution for my particular case consisted on modifying the way the file system was accessed so no synchronization was needed (a "sort of" map/reduce).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Measurement indicates that `RLock` is not I/O-bound. Although code that synchronizes with an `RLock` (or `Semaphore`) seems to be about 6 times slower than code without synchronization, code that does the simplest I/O is several orders of magnitude slower.

Below is the single-process code I used to measure `RLock` overhead with both Python and PyPy. I still don't understand why the overhead of `RLock` is so high over a single process,  or why the overhead doesn't maintain CPU/core utilization, but the results show that using standard synchronization primitives is much more efficient than trying to roll your own.

```
# lock.py
import sys
import os
import timeit
from random import random
from multiprocessing import RLock, Semaphore

N=8*1024*1024

lock = RLock()
semaphore = Semaphore()

def touch(fname, times=None):
    if not os.path.isfile(fname):
        open(fname, 'wa').close()
    else:
        with file(fname, 'a'):
            os.utime(fname, times)

def wolock():
    return random()

def wlock():
    with lock:
        return random()

def wsem():
    with semaphore:
        return random()

def wfile():
   os.path.isfile('lock')
   touch('lock') 
   try:
        return random()
   finally:
        os.unlink('lock')

def run(get):
    result = []
    for i in xrange(N):
        result.append(get())
    return result

def main():
    t0 = timeit.timeit('lock.wolock()', setup='import lock', number=N)
    print '%8.3f %8.2f%% %s' % (t0, 100, 'unsynchronized')
    t1 = timeit.timeit('lock.wlock()', setup='import lock', number=N)
    print '%8.3f %8.2f%% %s' % (t1, 100*t1/t0, 'rlock')
    t2 = timeit.timeit('lock.wsem()', setup='import lock', number=N)
    print '%8.3f %8.2f%% %s' % (t2, 100*t2/t0, 'semaphore')
    t = timeit.timeit('lock.wfile()', setup='import lock', number=N)
    print '%8.3f %s' % (t, 'file system')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Synchronisation between independent entities (i.e. processes, or hosts) requires that the two keep asking each other if anything has changed. This has a lot of subtle costs, such as by-passing caches to ensure all entities see the same data. Accessing uncached memory kill performance!

Comment: @RobM The example given uses a single process, and there's no resource contention.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how `multiprocessing` has implemented `RLock`. I am aware that multiprocessing *can* work across hosts which implies that synchronisation primitives may work across sockets. If that is true, it would introduce a lot of (variable) latency.

So I did an experiment.

Here's a noddy example of `RLock` being used by more than one process (to prevent any fast-path where all locks are within the same process):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep

lock = multiprocessing.RLock()

def noop(myname):
    # nonlocal lock
    sleep(0.5)
    print myname, "acquiring lock"
    with lock:
        print myname, "has lock"
        sleep(0.5)
    print myname, "released lock"

sProc1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=noop, args=('alice',))
sProc2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=noop, args=('bob',))

sProc1.start()
sProc2.start()

sProc1.join()
sProc2.join()
```

When this is run, its output looks something like this:

```
alice acquiring lock
alice has lock
bob acquiring lock
alice released lock
bob has lock
bob released lock
```

Great, so now run it with system call tracing via [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace).

In the command below, the `-ff` option tells the tool to "follow `fork()`" calls, i.e. trace any processes started by the main one. For reasons of brevity I'm also using `-e trace=futex,write`, which filters output based on conclusions I made before posting this. Normally you would run without the `-e` option and use a text editor / `grep` to explore what happened after the fact.

```
# strace -ff -e trace=futex,write ./traceme.py
futex(0x7fffeafe29bc, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 1, NULL, 7fb92ac6c700) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0x7fb92a8540b0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7fb92aa7131c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32) = 32
Process 25873 attached
Process 25874 attached
Process 25872 suspended
[pid 25873] write(1, "alice acquiring lock\n", 21alice acquiring lock
) = 21
[pid 25873] write(1, "alice has lock\n", 15alice has lock
) = 15
[pid 25874] write(1, "bob acquiring lock\n", 19bob acquiring lock
) = 19
[pid 25874] futex(0x7fb92ac91000, FUTEX_WAIT, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 25873] futex(0x7fb92ac91000, FUTEX_WAKE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 25874] <... futex resumed> )       = 0
[pid 25873] <... futex resumed> )       = 1
[pid 25874] write(1, "bob has lock\n", 13 <unfinished ...>
bob has lock
[pid 25873] write(1, "alice released lock\n", 20 <unfinished ...>
alice released lock
[pid 25874] <... write resumed> )       = 13
[pid 25873] <... write resumed> )       = 20
Process 25872 resumed
Process 25873 detached
[pid 25872] --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
Process 25872 suspended
[pid 25874] write(1, "bob released lock\n", 18bob released lock
) = 18
Process 25872 resumed
Process 25874 detached
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
```

From the pattern of print (`write()`) messages and [`futex`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futex) calls which block and later resume, it seems clear that `RLock` is implemented using `futex`, or "Fast Userspace Mutex". As the name implies this is a good choice for synchronisation.

When a process is blocked in a system-call like `futex` the process is blocking on I/O for all intents and purposes.

All this implies that `multiprocessing.RLock` is efficient and doing what it was designed to do. So if your application's performance is less than you expect when using synchronisation, chances are that your algorithm is to blame.

Comment: It seems you didn't read my own answer before answering yourself, but thanks for the analysis. `RLock` may have an efficient implementation, but it's as expensive as I had observed in my program.